# Using Spring jdbc template for List object params and multi column conditions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have list of transactions object having fields "accountnumber" and "systemcode" I'm trying to build query using jdbc template(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate) for sample below

**select *
from account
where (accountnumber,systemcode) in ((111,sys1),(222,sys2),.....)**

I'm using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate -I'm aware that If it one condition in WHERE IN clause I can use like

```
Set<String> listAccounts= //set with multiple values;
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("listAccounts", listAccounts);
List<Accounts> accounts= getJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT * FROM account WHERE accountnumber IN (:listAccounts)", parameters, getRowMapper());
```

Since this is multiple conditions in WHERE IN clause - this approach is not working for me - Please help

Answer (score 1):

*Option 1:* Dynamically build SQL `"SELECT * FROM account WHERE (accountnumber,systemcode) in ((?,?),(?,?),.....)"` and supply all the positional values to `JdbcTemplate.query(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)`

*Option 2:* Use SQL `"SELECT * FROM account WHERE accountnumber = :a AND systemcode = :s"` and use batching to run the statement for each pair of values, then merge all the results together in Java code.